# Dynamically map domains to folders in Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have multiple versions of the same software package in sub folders like this (simplified):

```
/var/www/version1
/var/www/version2
/var/www/version3
```

In a database I have a table similar to this:

```
+-----+-------------+----------+-----+
| ... | domain      | version  | ... |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----+
| ... | example.com | version1 | ... |
| ... | samepl.com  | version2 | ... |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----+
```

Is there any way, using a database as a source (MySQL as an example), to map URLs to the correct subfolder based on version and domain? I would like something dynamic that does not require an Apache restart.

The purpose of this setup is to allow customers to choose which version of the software they want. If there's a better way to do this I would love to hear that as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution on my own that involves VirtualHost variables.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html